# Solution of a system of second order algebraic equations in complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, complex-numbers

What is the simplest solution for this set of equations: 
$
\sum_{i=1,3,5,..}^{N-1} \left | x_i \right |^2=c_1,\  

\sum_{i=2,4,6,..}^{N} \left | x_i \right |^2=c_2,\ 

\sum_{i=1,3,5,..}^{N-1}  x_i {x_{i+1}}^{*} =c_3

$
where $x_i$ are in general complex and $c_i$ are constants. If no simple solution exists, do you know an algorithm to obtain one numerically?

Comment: The system seems underdetermined to me...

Comment: It is. So I am seeking an arbitrary solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand from your question that $N$ is even and $x^*$ represents the complex conjugate of $x$, and I will asume this in the following, as well as $c_1>0$, $c_2>0$ and $N\ge4$.

The Cauchy–Schwarz inequality implies that a necessary condition for the existence of a solution is that $|c_3|^2\le c_1\,c_2$. Under this condition, it is easy to obtain solutions like the folowing: $x_i=0$ for $i\ge4$, and for $0\le\theta,\phi<2\,\pi$,
$$
x_2=\sqrt{c_2}\,e^{i\theta},\quad x_1=\frac{c_3}{\sqrt{c_2}}\,e^{i\theta},\quad x_3=\sqrt{\frac{c_1\,c_2-|c_3|^2}{c_2}}\,e^{i\phi}\ .
$$

Wether it is simple is up to you.